# Plotting pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe as shown below.
I would like to plot the variable X_axis=bin_froup, Y_axis= rpercent, grouping the data by 'vintage'. And would like to have the legends at the bottom and would like to order them

the data is

```
    vintage bin_group   rpercent
0   bench   4   0.099920
1   bench   1   0.100086
2   bench   6   0.100221
3   bench   8   0.099710
4   bench   10  0.099830
5   bench   2   0.100191
6   bench   7   0.099950
7   bench   3   0.099950
8   bench   5   0.100116
9   bench   9   0.100026
10  2015Q1  5   0.101424
11  2015Q1  8   0.102468
12  2015Q1  7   0.099875
13  2015Q1  9   0.101738
14  2015Q1  6   0.098226
15  2015Q1  2   0.099202
16  2015Q1  4   0.098787
17  2015Q1  3   0.099034
18  2015Q1  1   0.096228
19  2015Q1  10  0.103018
20  2015Q2  6   0.100263
21  2015Q2  7   0.099659
22  2015Q2  2   0.095874
23  2015Q2  4   0.099835
24  2015Q2  10  0.109321
25  2015Q2  1   0.088201
26  2015Q2  9   0.105387
27  2015Q2  5   0.100012
28  2015Q2  8   0.104374
29  2015Q2  3   0.097073
30  2015Q3  9   0.103718
31  2015Q3  6   0.098387
32  2015Q3  7   0.101371
33  2015Q3  4   0.099649
34  2015Q3  10  0.106135
35  2015Q3  2   0.098680
36  2015Q3  3   0.097389
37  2015Q3  8   0.103190
38  2015Q3  1   0.090688
39  2015Q3  5   0.100793
```

Comment: i tried to reshape it as below abc=chart_dist.pivot(index='bin_group',columns='vintage',values='rpercent').reset_index()  and plot it as abc.plot() but it does not work

Comment: You should include what you've tried with an [edit] to your question, rather than in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataFrame.plot` check these instructions from [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.